# What is the WebProjectProperties section in the VS C# project file?

Tags: visual-studio

I had cloned a C# web application project to a new PC.  When I started debugging, I noticed in IISExpress that there were two instances.  One was https and the other http.

The project properties in Visual Studio was configured to use HTTPS

[image]

I edited the .csproj file and found this at the end of the file:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>64527</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>https://localhost:44327/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

DevelopmentServerPort is set to 6457 using the HTTP protocol, and it is not shown in the visual editor.  When I removed the port number and ran the project again, there was only one instance.  Also, the HTTPS runs where before I would get a connection error.

I also saw this at the top of the file in the PropertyGroup section:

```
<UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <Use64BitIISExpress />
    <IISExpressSSLPort>44327</IISExpressSSLPort>
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
```

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022.  The project was originally written using Visual Studio 2019.

Is the WebProjectProperties section left over from an earlier version of VS and can I safely delete it?